# java- how to get/use current date+time in query to SQL Server database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I want to store the current date+time into a table in SQL Server.

Separately, I also want to query the table (in which date+time was stored) and then obtain the date+time as a string value in format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

My program is in Java, and I am basically using a SQL Azure database.

I searched around for other questions similar to my own-- but the closest match on SO only deals with one part of date+time (not both date and time)

Comment: what are you using for db connectivity, straight JDBC or some ORM framework, such as Hibernate?

Comment: @foampile i am using straight jdbc....

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do: `GETDATE()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and [similar functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336248.aspx#datetime) will generate the current date and time in TSQL, and if you want the value in a specific format then either use `CONVERT()` or format it in Java. Formatting data is usually a client-side operation so doing it in Java would probably be better.